# How can I record the custom class that is extended from the SurfaceView class?

Tags: android, kotlin, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to record my custom class that is extended from the SurfaceView class. I'm using MediaRecorder for the purpose of recording.

I'm trying to record my custom class that is extended from the SurfaceView class. I few classes that work together using the Camera2 API. I'm trying to create a warp scan effect in Android. Those classes together make the warp effect using the camera2 API. Now I'm trying to record that effect as it's being created through my custom class using the MediaRecorder but it is giving me errors. Sometimes it gives me the error of stopping failed for the MediaRecorder sometimes some other exceptions.

```
`class Camera2SurfaceView : SurfaceView {
private val mEglUtils = EGLUtils()
private val videoRenderer = GLVideoRenderer()
private val mRenderer = GLRenderer()
private val scanRenderer = GLScanRenderer()
private var mCameraId: String? = null
private var mCameraManager: CameraManager? = null
private var mCameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession? = null
private var mCameraDevice: CameraDevice? = null
private var mHandler: Handler? = null
private var screenWidth = -1
private var screenHeight = 0
private var previewWidth = 0
private var previewHeight = 0
private val rect = Rect()
private var cameraHandler: Handler? = null
private var cameraThread: HandlerThread? = null
var isScanVideo = false
private var isf = false
private var scanHeight = 0f
private var pixelHeight = 0f
private val speed = 10

constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
    init()
}

constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
    init()
}

private fun init() {
    cameraThread = HandlerThread("Camera2Thread")
    cameraThread!!.start()
    cameraHandler = Handler(cameraThread!!.looper)
    initCamera2()
    holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        override fun surfaceCreated(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder) {
            cameraHandler!!.post {
                mEglUtils.initEGL(holder.surface)
                GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND)
                GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
                mRenderer.initShader()
                videoRenderer.initShader()
                scanRenderer.initShader()
                videoRenderer.setOnFrameAvailableListener {
                    cameraHandler!!.post(object : Runnable {
                        override fun run() {
                            if (mCameraCaptureSession == null) {
                                return
                            }
                            videoRenderer.drawFrame()
                            var videoTexture = videoRenderer.texture
                            if (isScanVideo) {
                                if (!isf) {
                                    scanHeight = pixelHeight * speed
                                } else {
                                    scanHeight += pixelHeight * speed
                                }
                                if (scanHeight < 2.0) {
                                    var fh = scanHeight
                                    if (scanHeight >= 1.0) {
                                        scanHeight = 3.0f
                                        fh = 1.0f
                                    }
                                    scanRenderer.drawFrame(videoRenderer.texture, fh)
                                }
                                videoTexture = scanRenderer.texture
                            }
                            isf = isScanVideo
                            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT or       GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
                            GLES20.glViewport(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width(), rect.height())
                            mRenderer.drawFrame(videoTexture)
                            mEglUtils.swap()
                        }
                    })
                }
                if (screenWidth != -1) {
                    openCamera2()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun surfaceChanged(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder, i: Int, w: Int, h: Int) {
            val sw = screenWidth
            screenWidth = w
            screenHeight = h
            cameraHandler!!.post {
                val mPreviewSize = getPreferredPreviewSize(mSizes, screenWidth, screenHeight)
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width
                pixelHeight = 1.0f / previewHeight
                val left: Int
                val top: Int
                val viewWidth: Int
                val viewHeight: Int
                val sh = screenWidth * 1.0f / screenHeight
                val vh = previewWidth * 1.0f / previewHeight
                if (sh < vh) {
                    left = 0
                    viewWidth = screenWidth
                    viewHeight = (previewHeight * 1.0f / previewWidth * viewWidth).toInt()
                    top = (screenHeight - viewHeight) / 2
                } else {
                    top = 0
                    viewHeight = screenHeight
                    viewWidth = (previewWidth * 1.0f / previewHeight * viewHeight).toInt()
                    left = (screenWidth - viewWidth) / 2
                }
                rect.left = left
                rect.top = top
                rect.right = left + viewWidth
                rect.bottom = top + viewHeight
                videoRenderer.setSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height)
                scanRenderer.setSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height)
                if (sw == -1) {
                    openCamera2()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun surfaceDestroyed(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder) {
            cameraHandler!!.post {
                if (mCameraCaptureSession != null) {
                    mCameraCaptureSession!!.device.close()
                    mCameraCaptureSession!!.close()
                    mCameraCaptureSession = null
                }
                GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND)
                videoRenderer.release()
                mRenderer.release()
                scanRenderer.release()
                mEglUtils.release()
            }
        }
    })
}

private var mSizes = arrayOf<Size>()
private fun initCamera2() {
    val handlerThread = HandlerThread("Camera2")
    handlerThread.start()
    mHandler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)
    mCameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    try {
        assert(mCameraManager != null)
        val CameraIdList = mCameraManager!!.cameraIdList
        mCameraId = CameraIdList[0]
        val characteristics = mCameraManager!!.getCameraCharacteristics(
            mCameraId!!
        )
        characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)
        val map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
        if (map != null) {
            mSizes = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture::class.java)
        }
    } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
private fun openCamera2() {
    if (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        try {
            mCameraManager!!.openCamera(mCameraId!!, stateCallback, mHandler)
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

private val stateCallback: CameraDevice.StateCallback = object : CameraDevice.StateCallback()  {
    override fun onOpened(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice
        takePreview()
    }

    override fun onDisconnected(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
        if (mCameraDevice != null) {
            mCameraDevice!!.close()
            mCameraDevice = null
        }
    }

    override fun onError(cameraDevice: CameraDevice, i: Int) {}
}

private fun takePreview() {
    try {
        val builder = mCameraDevice!!.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
        builder.addTarget(videoRenderer.mSurface!!)
        mCameraDevice!!.createCaptureSession(
            listOf(videoRenderer.mSurface!!),
            object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                override fun onConfigured(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession) {
                    if (null == mCameraDevice) return
                    mCameraCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession
                    builder.set(
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
                    )
                    builder.set(
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH
                    )
                    val previewRequest = builder.build()
                    try {
                        mCameraCaptureSession!!.setRepeatingRequest(
                            previewRequest,
                            null,
                            mHandler
                        )
                    } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }

                override fun onConfigureFailed(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession) {}
            },
            mHandler
        )
    } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private fun getPreferredPreviewSize(sizes: Array<Size>, width: Int, height: Int): Size {
    val collectorSizes: MutableList<Size> = ArrayList()
    for (option in sizes) {
        if (width > height) {
            if (option.width > width && option.height > height) {
                collectorSizes.add(option)
            }
        } else {
            if (option.height > width && option.width > height) {
                collectorSizes.add(option)
            }
        }
    }
    return if (collectorSizes.size > 0) {
        Collections.min(collectorSizes) { s1, s2 -> java.lang.Long.signum((s1.width * s1.height - s2.width * s2.height).toLong()) }
    } else sizes[0]
}
```

}
`
here is my custom class that extends the SurfaceView class. If anyone has any solution for me to record the warp scan effect that is being generated through this class kindly mention it in the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any details on how you're trying to connect the MediaRecorder to the renderer, so it's hard to say what might be wrong with your current approach.

But in general, you'd need to render to two destination surfaces from your GL renderers. One render pass to your SurfaceView Surface, and one identical render pass to your MediaRecorder Surface.

Comment: I have at least 6 classes that are connnected to this Camera2SurfaView class. But I was unable to post all the code in here.